# Wget slow download speed

Tags: linux, networking, debian, wget

I get horribly bad download speeds when I try to download files to Banana Pro (similar to Raspberry Pi) with wget. With wget, I get around 1.5-2MByte/s, while on another computer, I'm getting about 12MBytes/s. Both are connected to the same network, both with Gigabit cable. The speed via scp is about 11MBytes/s, so the Banana is able to achieve those speeds, just not with wget.

Comment: Are you paying attention to if the "B" in MB is a B or a b? Mb stands for Megabits and MB stands for Megabytes. There are 8 bits in a byte, so it sounds like this may just be a misconception of the two download speeds? I may be totally wrong and you are in fact having an issue with download speed, just thought I would ask.

Comment: 100% sure about the speeds. Thats why I emphasised, that I mean Bytes. Downlink is 120Mbits. Also, another quite effective measure is that downloading same file takes ~10 times longer.